# the sChanging Case Owner to a Queue manually

Tags: case, queue, ownership

I'm using a test user to change the case owner to a queue but when I search for a Queue this is shown. I already created queues and the user is a member of that queue.

Any help please?

Thank you.

[image]

Here is screenshot of my Queue

[image]

Comment: While creating queue, have you selected Object under it?

Comment: Hi @Ayub yes it's under Case. Which is where I needed.

Comment: can u plz add a screenshot of queue your config?

Comment: Hi @Ayub I've now attached the screenshot of my Queue

Comment: It's bizarre. It happens sometimes when you just create and just try to search! but I do not think that's your case. May be try with full name in between

Comment: I've tried that one but still didn't work. Thank you @ayub. I'll just create a Case to salesforce support

Comment: Plz share whatever you find. Thanks.

Comment: @Ayub this is a bug in spring 20'

Comment: I knew that. This spring release is going to kill us ...lot of issues.